# Column means over multiple files

Tags: r

I have multiple files that contain values in columns (columns are the same for each file).  Now I want to calculate values like the mean or sd for each column over all files, e.g., `output_value1 = mean(file1_value1, file2_value1, ..., filen_value1)`. I have a lot of files, so doing that by hand is clearly not an option.

How do I calculate e.g. the mean in a new table like in the following example?

```
# INPUT
################

file1.txt
id, value1, value2
1,  10,     100
2,  5,      25
3,  10,     50

file2.txt
id, value1, value2
1,  2,      200
2,  7,      15
3,  10,     50

file3.txt
id, value1, value2
1,  3,      30
2,  6,      5
3,  10,     100

# OUTPUT
################

id value1 value2
1  5      110
2  6      15
3  10     66.6
```

I have already managed to read the data by using

```
Files <- Sys.glob("*.txt")
m <- lapply(Files, read.csv, header=TRUE, comment.char="#")
```

How do I go on from here?

Comment: `Output[1,"value2"]` is 110, I suppose.

Comment: @Codoremifa Thanks, that's why I use tools like R ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `data.table` library:

```
library(data.table)

# reading each file as a data.table. Bonus - fread is much faster than read.csv
m <- lapply(Files, fread, header=TRUE, comment.char="#")

#compiling into one dataset
m2 <- rbindlist(m)

#calculating mean by id over each column
m2[,lapply(.SD,mean),by="id"]
```